# AVD uses 100% CPU after PC`s hibernation, how to solve?

Tags: hibernate

When I hibernate my PC with running AVD and turn it on later, AVD uses 100% CPU and there are hard lags. How to solve this one if I want to continue using hibernation?

Comment: You should not hibernate while virtual machines are running.

Comment: What OS is the computer running?